# Generate n dependene moving average structure

Tags: time-series, independence, high-dimensional

In `Chen and qin (2010)` ([available here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1266586615)), a moving average structure for generating moving average model introduced that is like this:

$ X_{jk} = \rho_1Z_{jk} + \rho_2Z_{j(k+1)} +\dots+ \rho_pZ_{j(k+p-1)} + \mu_{j} $

which $j \in \{ 1,2,\dots, n \}$, $k \in \{ 1,\dots,p\}$, and $n$ and $p$ are size and dimension of date respectively. suppose $Z$s are standard normal variables and $\rho$s are fix for all dimensions. `Chen and qin (2010)` says that for `Two Dependent Case`, $X_{jk_1}$ and $X_{jk_2}$ dependent if $\lvert k_1 - k_2 \lvert \leq 2$.

How Can I generate such dependent time series and get covariance matrix of theme?

Comment: Note that you replaced $p$ by $n$ in the formula. Now, are you asking about why there called the case of $ p \le 3 $ "two dependence", or just on how to generate such data? If the later, what programming language do you use?

Comment: @tmrlvi oh! thanks. my mistake. I use preferably  `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that you can calculate the covariance function from the model. Note that the covariance for all pair of rows is the same as their distribution is different only in their mean.

$$ \gamma\left(h\right) = Cov\left(X_{j,k},X_{j,k+h}\right) = \sum_{t = 0}^{p-1} \sum_{s = 0}^{p-1} \rho_t \rho_s Cov\left(Z_{j,k+s},Z_{j,k+h+t}\right) \\
= 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{t = 0}^{p-1 - \left|h\right|} \rho_t \rho_{t+\left|h\right|} & \left|h\right|<p \\
0 & o.w.
\end{cases}$$

The covariance matrix between the rows will be
$$
\Sigma_{i,j} = \gamma\left(\left| i - j\right|\right)
$$

Now, we can generate the data, and compute the empirical covariance. We'll generate $n$ vectors of length $d$, where each is a moving average of $p+d-1$ random variables with windows of size $p$.

```
# Calculate d moving averages with window size p out of vector of size p+d-1
ma <- function(row, rho){
  return(sapply(seq(1, length(row) - length(rho) + 1), function(loc){
    sum(row[loc:(loc+length(rho)-1)] * rho)
  }))
}

n <- 10000
d <- 13
p <- 10

# Model parameters
rho <- rep(1, p)
mu <- rep(1,n)

# Generating Gaussian vectors
Z <- matrix(rnorm(n = n*(p+d-1)), ncol=p+d-1)

# Applying the moving average with rho. Note that apply transpose the matrix.
X.centered <- t(apply(Z, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) {ma(row, rho)}))

# Add the mean
X <- X.centered + mu

# Calculate the empirical covariance 
#(note that the function cov also estimates the mean)
X.empirical_cov <- (t(X - mu) %*% (X - mu))/n
```

Note that in the models parameters I choose, $\Sigma_{i,j} = \max\left\lbrace p - \left|i-j\right|, 0 \right\rbrace$.

Comment: You are the life saver :).